# How to avoid null body from entering into next processor in multiple steps

Tags: java, apache-camel, integration

How can I restrict the null body from entering into multiple processor at one common place. In below code instead of putting null body check at every processor, how can I define it at a single place ?

```
<choice>
    <when>
        <simple>${body} != null</simple>
        <process ref="processor1" />
        <choice>
            <when>
                <simple>${body} != null</simple>
                <process ref="processor2" />
                <!-- Splitter -->
                <split>
                    <simple>body</simple>
                    <process ref="processor3" />
                </split>
            </when>   
        </choice>
    </when>
</choice>
```

Comment: If the null message is inappropriate for given processor, why not define it in the processor itself and ignore (re-send) the null?

Comment: can you give me an example how to do it in processor ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you leave the root all-together, thus rendering further null checks obsolete. A quick and easy way to stop route-processing for your current message is setting the `Exchange.ROUTE_STOP` property on your `exchange` object AND return `null`:

```
exchange.getProperty(Exchange.ROUTE_STOP, Boolean.TRUE)
```

Comment: I think you meant `exchange.setProperty(Exchange.ROUTE_STOP, Boolean.TRUE);`

Answer (score 1):

Code in comment will be awfully displayed, so i post an answer.
Doing it in processor is a simple null check, no philosophy

```
public class SomeProcessor implements Processor {

    public void process(Exchange exchange) {
        if(exchange.getIn().getBody() != null){
            // Your processing here
            // Is only performed
            // When body is not null
            // Otherwise null body is being resent
        }
    }

}
```

Edit (answer to comment):
It is not possible AFAIK and it wouldn't be a proper way to do it.
[Router](http://camel.apache.org/message-router.html) which you're already using is how it should be performed.
If you want to throw away your message, i think this could work(i didn't check it, though):

```
<choice>
    <when>
        <simple>${body} == null</simple>
        #<stop />
        # OR
        #<to uri="wherever-you-want-to-send-nonvalid-messages" />
    </when>
    <otherwise>
        <camel:process ref="processor1" />
        <camel:process ref="processor2" />
        <camel:process ref="processor3" />
        <to uri="where-you-want-to-send-valid-messages" />
    </otherwise>

</choice>
```

It will only check for nulls before first processor, obviously, so if i.e. second processor gives null out message, it will not be thrown out.

Comment: Yes, but it should only be done if null is not a valid in-body for a processor.
Processor is supposed to be re-usable (in many places inside your xml, for example), so if you wanted to specify, that null is not a correct message in a single routing, the code in original post would be good enough i guess.

Comment: If body is null, just come out of camel route..Is it possible ? I mean from the processor body ?

Answer (score 1):

By adding an `<stop>` tag you can do this.

```
<choice>
    <when>
        <simple>${body} != null</simple>
        <stop></stop>            
    </when>   
    <otherwise>
        <process ref="processor2" />
        <!-- Splitter -->
        <split>
        <simple>body</simple>
        <process ref="processor3" />
        </split>
    <otherwise>
</choice>
```